# Handle JSON request with Apache Camel

Tags: java, json, jetty, apache-camel

I want to handle an HTTPs request that a 3rd party is doing towards my system. The requests contains a JSON object

I have tried using the Jetty component of Camel but when the 3rd party performs the requests Camel throws the following exception:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Cannot read request parameters due Invalid parameter, expected to be a pair but was {"id":"321","rec":"533","status":"ok"}
```

The Jetty endpoint is defined in blueprint as:

```
<camel:endpoint id="getRequestEndpoint" uri="jetty:{{webServiceProtocol}}://{{jettyIp}}:{{jettyPort}}/getRequest?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"/>
```

Am I missing something or are in a totally wrong path?

Comment: Have you tried to get it to work without SSL first? Usually it is best to test this without SSL and then add the HTTPS part so at least you know everything else is working correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your client is sending the appropriate `Content-Type` HTTP request header for JSON, which is:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

It looks like it wasn't sent and the Jetty component falls back to form data interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also add expected bean type to your endpoint definition, like this:

```
.post()
    .type(User.class)
    .to("direct:your-queue")
```

This is strictly speaking not an answer, because in this case you get a different exception shown below. But I hope it helps someone.

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: 
com.example.User but has value: {id=69, name=Hello world} of type: 
java.util.LinkedHashMap
```